# html elements not lining up using colspan

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a table with 3 rows.
I decided to split each row into 4 columns even though the most TDs a row will have is two.

So, the top row with one TD, has a colspan of 4.

the next row has two TDs, the first with a colspan of 1, the second with a colspan of 3.

the third row has two TDs, each with a colspan of 2.

here is the HTML:

```
    <table class="img">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="ttBtn"><hr></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='1'>
                <select id="moveShifts">
                    <option val="1">1st Shift</option>
                    <option val="2">2nd Shift</option>
                    <option selected="" val="3">3rd Shift</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td colspan='3' style='display:block' dept="3">
                <select id="moveDepts">
                    <option val="139">CO-MAIL 1</option>
                    <option val="140">CO-MAIL 2</option>
                    <option val="599">FORKLIFT</option>
                    <option val="665">LEAD TEMP</option>
                    <option selected="" val="666">OPERATOR</option>
                    <option val="16">PAMS-CTLMAIL</option>
                    <option val="463">PAMS-CTLMAIL GEN LAB ** DO NOT USE **</option>
                    <option val="141">PAMS-CTLPAL</option>
                    <option val="540">POLY BAG</option>
                    <option val="485">RECEIVING</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <input type="button" value="Update Punch Record" class="ttBtn" disabled='true' id="ttUpd">
            </td>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <input type="button" value="Delete Punch Record" class="ttBtn" id="ttDel">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It looks like the second button on the bottom row won't shift left any closer the the right end of the select element above it.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to fix this?

Here is a link to the code on JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Joth/TdVAd/2/

Thanks!

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/TdVAd/3/  ?

Comment: Thanks Derek - that looks like it will work great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code...

```
 <tr>
   <td colspan='4'>
    <input type="button" value="Update Punch Record" class="ttBtn" disabled='true' id="ttUpd">
    <input type="button" value="Delete Punch Record" class="ttBtn" id="ttDel">
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is 'display:block;' in TD element (if you add border to table, you show it):

```
            <td colspan="3" style='display:table-cell' dept="3">
```

You can use tag COLGROUP and set width at tag COL, for example:

```
 <table class="img">
        <colgroup><col width="25%" /><col width="25%" /><col width="25%" /><col width="25%" /></colgroup>
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Magicianred/T9Ru5/4/

Enjoy your code